# Having trouble with NaN. Tried to fix it, added a gazillion parseInts and parseFloats to try and fix it, didn't work

Tags: javascript

I am just learning javascript and I now know enough to make a measly little dumb project for practice. I was making something called the "AverageFinder". At this point, I had written 39 lines of code(roughly because I optimized my code) and so I added an alert function at the end to see if things were working so far. I was not expecting this, and I knew the general area of the problem. I got NaN also known as Not a Number, and yet I was using variables with no quotes, so it should not have given me NaN. After many puzzled hours and trying to find something on StackOverflow(I found nothing), I tried inputting loads of parseInt and parseFloat commands by my variables, but It still gave me NaN.
Please help and explain to me what the problem is, but remember, I am a beginner. My code is below. P.S. I code with repl.it, so you may want to run my code there. I want total_added to display its value instead of giving me NAN.Thanks!

```
alert ("This website will find an average for you!")
var how_many_numbers_are_they_averaging = prompt ("how many numbers are you finding the average of?")

how_many_numbers_are_they_averaging = (parseInt (how_many_numbers_are_they_averaging) + 1)

var current_number_out_of_numbers_they_are_averaging = (1)
var listy = []

while (current_number_out_of_numbers_they_are_averaging !== how_many_numbers_are_they_averaging) {
  var add_this_to_the_list = prompt("what is your " + current_number_out_of_numbers_they_are_averaging + " number you want to average")

  add_this_to_the_list = (parseInt(add_this_to_the_list))

  listy.push(add_this_to_the_list)

  current_number_out_of_numbers_they_are_averaging = (current_number_out_of_numbers_they_are_averaging + 1)

}
var currentnum
currentnum = parseFloat(currentnum)
currentnum = parseInt(currentnum)
how_many_numbers_are_they_averaging = (parseInt(how_many_numbers_are_they_averaging))
var temp_list_num
var total_added
var onenrip = (0)
var two = (1)
var add1 = parseInt(listy[onenrip]) 
var add2 = parseInt(listy[onenrip])
total_added = (add1 + add2)
currentnum = (2)
while (currentnum != how_many_numbers_are_they_averaging){
 temp_list_num = parseInt(listy[currentnum])
 total_added = parseInt(total_added)
  total_added = (total_added + temp_list_num)
  total_added = parseInt(total_added);
  currentnum = (currentnum + 1)
}
currentnum = parseInt(currentnum)
alert(total_added)
```

Comment: You gave a lot of irrelevant information; but I can't figure out what you are asking. May I suggest you read guidance https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and try again...

Comment: I basically just need someone to run my code, tell me what was wrong, and give it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the top line of your second while loop to the following:

```
while (currentnum < how_many_numbers_are_they_averaging - 1) {
```

This will prevent your program from trying to access values in the array that don't exist (for example, if the user is averaging 5 numbers together, you don't want your program to try to access `listy[5]`, `listy[6]`, etc.) Attempting to access these values sets your `total_added` variable to NaN when you try to add them in.

Comment: wow! thanks. I had no idea! this totally helped!